# Why does Tabulator subtract one day from the date entered when using moment.js as date formatter?

Tags: momentjs, tabulator

Please see the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rpowell6/adwu7x6e/22/.

A single day is being subtracted from any date entered, either manually or using the date picker.  The `dateEditor` function is taken from the `Tabulator` web site and makes use of `moment.js` for formatting.

Any assistance in determining why the day is being subtracted would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was experiencing resulted from improperly copying a `moment.js` `format()` statement.  This issue has been resolved.